# Why 朝に instead of just 朝? 「月曜日の朝にその本を読みました」

Tags: grammar, particle-に

It's often said that relative time expressions don't take the time marker に, but why can I find sentences like these:

> 月曜日の朝にその本を読みました。

> ジンジャーさんとスコットさんは、朝にシャワーを浴びてから、仕事に行く。

> 私たちは明日の朝にその家を出ます。

> じゃ、早く寝たら、明日の朝にはよくなるでしょう。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

に cannot be omitted in the last sentence.

> じゃ、早く寝たら、明日の朝**には**よくなるでしょう。

This には indicates a time **by** which something happens.

に is indeed optional in the other three sentences. The versions with に give an impression of pinpointing the time of the event, possibly for emphasis, when compared with the versions without に.